# MetadataException : connection string

Tags: c#, .net, connection-string, edmx

I realise that this question has been asked and solved many times before here and that there are many helpful posts such as this one...http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/08/13/38628/
But unfortunately none of the suggestions have worked for me, so I'm posting in the hope that someone might spot something I haven't seen.

I have a database project Sp_CodeGenerator - I've connected to the database. My connection string is

`<add name="AdWorksLTEntities"     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Sp_CodeGenerator.Model1.csdl|res://*/Sp_CodeGenerator.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Sp_CodeGenerator.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=EIRCOM;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT2008R2;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>`

I have tried substituting `//*/Sp_CodeGenerator.Model...` with the name of the dll `//Sp_CodeGenerator/Sp_CodeGenerator.Model.csdl` etc  But it doesn't work.

I have also removed all references in the .config file, removed the .edmx file and the template files generated by Entity Frameworks and started over many times, but it doesn't work.

I can see in my directory structure that the edmx files :Model1.csdl, Model1.msl, Model1.ssdl  are housed in a folder called edmxResourcesToEmbed and they can be found in C:\Sp_CodeGenerator\Sp_CodeGenerator\obj\x86

So the full path is 
            C:\Sp_CodeGenerator\Sp_CodeGenerator\obj\x86\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed

I'm not sure if it is a coincidence, but once the problem appeared I also noticed that I have several messages once I open the .config file about missing schemas for element 'entityFramework' 'defaultconnectionFactory' 'type' etc etc.

Any suggestions of where to look next, greatly appreciated.

The full stack trace on the MetadataException is

```
  at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource.LoadResource()
  at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource.CreateReader()
  at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderResource.CreateReaders(DataSpace        spaceToGet)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderComposite.CreateReaders(DataSpace  spaceToGet)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.EdmMetadataEntry.LoadEdmItemCollection(MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.EdmItemCollectionLoader.LoadItemCollection(EdmMetadataEntry entry)
  at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry)
  at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateEdmItemCollection(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, Object& entryToken)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadEdmItemCollection(MetadataWorkspace workspace, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)
  at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)
  at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
  at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
  at System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy[TSource,TKey](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 keySelector)
  at Sp_CodeGenerator.SelectAll.SelectAll_Method() in    C:\Sp_CodeGenerator\Sp_CodeGenerator\Templates\dbo.SelectAll.StoredProcedure.sql.xml.cs:line 14
  at Sp_CodeGenerator.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Sp_CodeGenerator\Sp_CodeGenerator\Program.cs:line 15
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - I just needed to remove the Sp_CodeGenerator. from infront each Model1 in the connection string.  Not really sure why the connection string was generated like that in the first place?  Maybe something to do with my directory structure?